# MYSQL distinct not working 23

Tags: mysql

I have query like below

```
select distinct TopName, Occurrences, State, Year
From topbabynamesbystate
where Gender = "F" and State = "WA" and (year >= 2000)
order by Occurrences desc
limit 3
```

the name emily still shows up twice in the data set.

Comment: Distinct returns the distinct combinations of the selected columns.

Comment: Distinct is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is something like

> SELECT DISTINCT TopName 
>   FROM topbabynamesbystate AS t1
>   INNER JOIN TopName AS t2 ON t1.TopName = t2.TopName
>   WHERE Gender = "F" 
>   AND State = "WA" 
>   AND (year >= 2000)